# SKS key-server cannot import key-dump

Tags: openpgp, keyserver

I am on a desktop *with lots of memory (64 GB)* and cannot make sks key-server work. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and I am using kernel `5.4.23-050423-generic` (installed with Ukuu Kernel Update Utility).

I have downloaded a key-dump (~14 GB of .pgp files) and placed it in `/var/lib/sks/dump`. Then I run:

```
sudo chown -R debian-sks:debian-sks /var/lib/sks
sudo su debian-sks
cd /var/lib/sks
/usr/lib/sks/sks_build.sh
```

If I choose `normalbuild` (option 2), I get the following output:

```
=== Running build... === 
Loading keys...done
DB time:  0.33 min.  Total time: 0.37 min.
... ...
Loading keys...Fatal error: exception Stack overflow
Command failed unexpectedly. Bailing out
```

If, as user `debian-sks`, I run

```
sks build /var/lib/sks/dump/*.pgp -n 10 -cache 100
```

I get a segmentation fault/core dump. Same result with various option combinations.

Option 1 of the script (`fastbuild`) also gives `Fatal error: exception Stack overflow`. I have also tried to build sks key-server from source ([from here](https://github.com/SKS-Keyserver/sks-keyserver)), but again I get a segmentation fault when running the script (I have only tried option 2 - `normalbuild`).

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be relevant: https://github.com/SKS-Keyserver/sks-keyserver/issues/65

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome the *Stack overflow/segmentation fault* it appears `ulimit -s 65536` does the trick (16384 is not enough -- I have not tried 32768). I would suggest package maintainers to add a test and invocation of `ulimit -s ...` in file `sks_build.sh`.

There is an other workaround in [this comment](https://github.com/SKS-Keyserver/sks-keyserver/issues/65#issuecomment-778646134) of github issue *"SKS Segnentation Fault During FastBuild #65"*. Nevertheless, it does not work for me, since `sks merge dump/*.pgp` also crashes.

Anyway, in my case, `sks build dump/*.pgp` now crashes --much later-- the same way as `sks merge dump/*.pgp`, with `Fatal error: exception Sys_error("1: No such file or directory")`. This would appear to be a new error...

[ **Solved this as well:** Somewhere I found an `sksconf` setting of `disable_mailsync: 1`. This cannot be; it can be just `disable_mailsync:`. The former creates this totally unexpected `Fatal error: exception Sys_error("1: No such file or directory")`. ]